# QGIS - Attachment with a photo in the attributes does not show the photo and the button to open the file dialog

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, photos, attachments, attribute-form

I received a QGIS map project with data that I needed to update. So I chose the Change data source layer and selected the updated data. Now I'm supposed to continue updating the data, but the upload image button has disappeared. How can I fix this?

Previously:
[image]

After adding updated data:
[image]

The attribute form settings seem correct.
[image]

Comment: When you changed the data source, was the new data source in the same location (relative to the image locations)? If for example your original data source was in C:\Project and images in C:\Project\Photo ... But you change the data source to a file in C:\Project\Data then the image widget will be looking in the wrong area for the images. As for the file selection button going missing, I'm not sure, but double check that the field's widget is still an image widget (layer properties > attribute form).

Comment: The photos location is set as a relative path, that should be fine.

Checking the settings in the attribute form did not help. (I added a screenshot to the post)